# remove unallocated elasticsearch shard

Tags: elasticsearch

My installation is working fine, but one index is showing yellow health due to 2 'extra' unassigned shards shown in it.  How do I remove these extra shards?  My current settings are 0 replicas and 2 shards.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health/tags?level=shards&pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_inspire",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 2,
  "active_shards" : 2,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2,
  "indices" : {
    "v1_tags" : {
      "status" : "yellow",
      "number_of_shards" : 2,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 2,
      "active_shards" : 2,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 2,
      "shards" : {
        "0" : {
          "status" : "yellow",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 1,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 1
        },
        "1" : {
          "status" : "yellow",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 1,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had this issue where ES process was restarted on all nodes and I had some unassigned shards (cluster health was red).
I did the following to assign the shards manually and that did the trick for me (no restart was needed)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "INDEXNAME",
        "shard": "SHARDNUMBER",
        "node": "PICKANODE",
        "allow_primary": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: Could you walk through what this does a bi tmore?  Presumably you put specific values in indexname/shardnumber/node

Comment: I had several unassigned shards like these: "unassigned" : [ {
    "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : null,
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "logstash-2014.01.14"
    }, 
In the command mentioned, I entered indexname as `logstash-2014.01.14`, shard as 0 and node: any of the nodename from my 3 node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the node seemed to be the only way to solve it.

If anyone has a less-aggressive solution, please post it :)